# SQL , get difference b/w to id's

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get result from two tables:

Table A

```
create table A
( propertyId int not null
 ,PRIMARY KEY (propertyId))
```

Table B

```
create table B
( Id int not null
, propertyId int
, FOREIGN KEY (propertyId ) REFERENCES A(propertyId))
```

Now I want to get the result total count id of `Table A` exist in `Table B` AND total count id that does not exist in `Table B`

```
SELECT COUNT(property.propertyId) AS 'Occupied'
    ,(
        SELECT COUNT(property.propertyId)
        FROM property
        INNER JOIN agreement ON property.`propertyId` <> agreement.`propertyId`
        ) AS 'Vacant'
FROM property
INNER JOIN agreement ON property.`propertyId` = agreement.`propertyId`
WHERE agreement.`isActive` = '1'
```

Comment: i have tried this query but its not working for vacant. SELECT COUNT(property.propertyId) AS 'Occupied',(SELECT COUNT(property.propertyId) FROM property 
JOIN agreement
ON property.`propertyId` <> agreement.`propertyId`) 
AS 'Vacant'
FROM property 
JOIN agreement
ON property.`propertyId` = agreement.`propertyId` 
WHERE agreement.`isActive`='1'

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you have sample data and desired results?  Edit your question and include the query you have tried.

Comment: @GordonLinoff check my comment.... and excuse me for table names are different  in my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution should be based on this principle, also exemplified in [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65ddc/5):

```
SELECT count(CASE 
            WHEN propertyID IS NOT NULL
                AND fk_propertyID IS NOT NULL
                THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
            END) 'exist_in_both_tables'
    ,count(CASE 
            WHEN propertyID IS NOT NULL
                AND fk_propertyID IS NULL
                THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
            END) 'does_not_exist_in_b'
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM tablea a
    LEFT JOIN tableb b ON a.propertyID = b.fk_propertyID

    UNION

    SELECT *
    FROM tablea a
    RIGHT JOIN tableb b ON a.propertyID = b.fk_propertyID
    ) result
```

You need to duplicate your query and use both `LEFT` and `RIGHT` joins and `UNION` the results of those two separate queries to simulate the result of a `FULL JOIN`.

After simulating this, you need to go over this result set again, by making this a sub-query and then using aggregate functions, `COUNT()`, along with `CASE` statements to count how many matches you have in both tables.

Hence, your final queries should look something like this:

```
SELECT count(CASE 
            WHEN Property_PropertyID IS NOT NULL
                AND Agreement_PropertyID IS NOT NULL
                THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
            END) 'Occupied'
    ,count(CASE 
            WHEN Property_PropertyID IS NOT NULL
                AND Agreement_PropertyID IS NULL
                THEN 1
            ELSE NULL
            END) 'Vacant'
FROM (
    SELECT property.propertyID 'Property_PropertyID'
    FROM property
    LEFT JOIN agreement ON property.`propertyId` = agreement.`propertyId`
    WHERE agreement.`isActive` = '1'

    UNION

    SELECT agreement.propertyID 'Agreement_PropertyID'
    FROM property
    RIGHT JOIN agreement ON property.`propertyId` = agreement.`propertyId`
    WHERE agreement.`isActive` = '1'
    ) ResultSet
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `Left join` to get the proper result.

```
select 
sum (
  case when a.propertyId is not null then 1
  else 0
  end
) as present_cnt,

sum (
  case when a.propertyId is null then 1
  else 0
  end
) as not_present_cnt

from property p 
left join agreement a on p.propertyId = a.propertyId
where a.isActive = '1';
```

`left join` will fetch data for `a.propertyId` from `agreement` corresponding to `p.propertyId`, if no match found then `null`